# React Native 'expo-video-player' - network video doesn't work, when there is "+" in URL

Tags: react-native, expo

Everything is fine, when URI looks like that - [https://x.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test.mp4.m3u8"](https://x.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test.mp4.m3u8%22). Unfortunately, on a S3 bucket that I don't have access to, some URLs look like that [https://x.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test+something.mp4.m3u8"](https://x.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test+something.mp4.m3u8%22). Every link with this plus sign gives me error "Encountered a fatal error during playback: The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1008 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain". How can I fix it?